# firebase push notification is not working on app killed state in some devices (Android)

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

firebase push notifications are not working in some vivo devices.
getting this on logcat when push is received:

broadcast intent callback result=cancelled forintent

Answer (score 0):

The push is working.
You should recheck the documentation.
Your receiver can't catch push because firebase doesn't call it in the background state.

[firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#handling_messages)